# numberformat error with bigs numbers in php

Tags: php, number-formatting

I'm developing a e-commerce and I have a problem when I want to format a number with number_format().

I have to set to my Stripe connection a number without decimals, so when I do all the calculations to have the final price of my shoppingcart I do:

```
$final_amount = number_format($final_amount, 2) * 100;
```

The result is a number that Stripe understands. I haven't got any problem with small numbers (like 970.25 or 1300.75 for example) but when I have a big amount like 15717.72 php throws the error "A non well formed numeric value encountered". I don't know if this is the problem, big numbers.

I've tried to parse previously $final_amount with floatval() and It didn't run either.

Someone knows the problem? thanks :)

Comment: [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) returns a string with comma-grouped thousands by default.

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by "with floatval() and It didn't run either."?  What _did_ happen?  Seems to me that it would produce a valid result, so you need to be clear about in what way it wasn't what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple notes.

*"A non well formed numeric value encountered"* is a **Notice**, not an **Error**.

I don't believe *1300.75* works for you. The reason I don't believe this is you are only giving [number_format](https://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) two parameters. You are receiving that notice because number_format is formatting your number with a thousands separator ",".

```
$final_amount = number_format($final_amount, 2, ".", "") * 100;
```

should do the trick to remove that notice.

Answer (score 0):

problem is not number_format() function but your calculation. You are multiplying a string with an integer. That does not work out so well.

```
$final_amount = number_format($final_amount * 100, 2);
```

Works just fine.

Update:
My conclusion was not completely correct. Multiplying an int with an string does work if the string is castable to int or float (see [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) in PHP manual). But the string created by number_format() looks like this: "15,717.72". And thus cannot be cast to a number type.